# What design pattern to locate my IUnitOfWork?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, persistence-ignorance

I've implemented a repository pattern with persistence ignorance. The repository implementation only interacts with my entity objects, `IUnitOfWork` and `ITable<T>` interfaces. The intention is that the `IUnitOfWork` isn't reused but represents a single transaction. So far, I've implemented in-memory as well as Linq-to-Sql versions of the `IUnitOfWork` and `ITable<T>`.

My problem is that due to the `IUnitOfWork` injection into the repository, I end up with needing to know how to instantiate a new `IUnitOfWork` where ever the repository is used. Since this is the primary piece that is supposed to be pluggable it feels like I've done something wrong. The general usage pattern is something like this:

```
FooUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new FooUnitOfWork();
Repository repos = new Repository(unitOfWork);
// ...act upon repos
unitOfWork.Save();
```

Now it appears that I need some other pattern to allow every repository usage in the app to obtain the correct unit of work (e.g. in-memory, L2S, etc.).

**What is the most fitting pattern for this?** I've looked at [Fowler's discussion on the topic](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#InversionOfControl) but none of his examples seem to be a clean fit. I already feel like the amount of abstraction that I have is more than I'd like so building yet another indirection seems excessive.

At the moment, I'm leaning toward some sort of app-wide provider which can be configured to produce the correct `IUnitOfWork`. Am I off-base or is this what is needed to truly be implementation agnostic?

Comment: Well, you need a context to associate the unit of work with (such as a thread or httpcontext), you then need to use a factory method to get the unit of work (vs new()).

Comment: A static factory method (backed by a thread context) would be a clean interface for instantiation. How about for setting up the configuration (DB context, etc) that I currently setup in the `UnitOfWork` constructors?

Comment: I would handle this in some places authoritive, if this was a web application for example.. you would handle BeginRequest and create a unit of work (passing in all your dependencies and config), and then save it somewhere (the easiest would be either instance members in the global, or in the Items collection), you would then have a factory method (or something similar) that would know where to look for the work unit instance... you can work to make something far more sophisticated but really all you are doing is setting up a service ...

Comment: I'm leaning toward an `IUnitOfWorkFactory.Create` type pattern, as I can't create a single `IUnitOfWork` for the app. There are threading concerns and for the Linq-to-Sql implementation it is recommended to not keep `DataContext` objects around very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** while this didn't really break down it ended up just producing a poor-man's IoC Container. I ended up just replacing all of these:

```
UnitOfWorkFactory.Create();
```

with the generalized [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=17694) implementation:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
```

This allowed me to create a library which uses Dependency Injection without forcing all users to use the same IoC framework.

---

Perhaps I should use a very simple factory where I can set a callback? It could have a set of static methods on it like this:

```
public static class UnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private static Func<IUnitOfWork> FactoryMethod;

    public static IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        if (UnitOfWorkFactory.FactoryMethod == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("...");
        }

        return UnitOfWorkFactory.FactoryMethod();
    }

    public static void SetFactoryMethod(Func<IUnitOfWork> factory)
    {
        UnitOfWorkFactory.FactoryMethod = factory;
    }
}
```

Where does this break down?

Comment: Since there hasn't been a better solution I guess I'm rolling with this. I would still be interested in hearing where this breaks down or if someone has another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Vistor pattern to discover the implementations of the IUnitOfWork interface.

```
[UnitOfWork(Name="foo")]
public class FooUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {}

Repository repo = new Repository("foo");
//stuff happens
repo.Save(); //or repo.Worker.Save();
```

Inside the repo instance a discovery factory finds the worker and creates it.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that makes it easier to determine *which* `IUnitOfWork` implementation I want.  The code that uses it will be the same for all implementations, otherwise I'd just instantiate the `IUnitOfWork` I want.

Comment: Using an attribute(s) and a runtime locator like visitor, you can mark up the implementations with metadata that allow your factory to choose the best fit.

Comment: There is nothing for it to switch off of. Every instantiation in the logic is exactly the same (e.g. your example without passing in "foo") because it is at a app-wide configuration level that the storage mechanism is chosen. It's much more analogous to the ASP.NET Provider model.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question...app-wide configuration suggests keeping the switch in a config file. You can extend the system.configuration classes if you want something more than a simple string key. This is how the asp.net providers and wcf channels get selected.